# Does Alchemy4Tridion work with SDL Tridion Sites 9?

Tags: a4t, sites-9

Does [Alchemy4Tridion](https://www.alchemywebstore.com/) work with SDL Tridion Sites 9?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, it is currently not supported.  We're awaiting the release of Tridion Sites 9.1 + to examine the changes made to the GUI.

Comment: Thanks for the update, John! Tridion Sites 9.1 UI will mostly rebrand product names while introducing planned features related to integrations and their management. See upcoming webinars on SDL Community on the 9.1 scope.

Comment: so there will be no support for SDL Tridion Sites 9? or is there a way to get it to work with the latest version of the framework, like bypassing the product check?

Comment: There's no way to get it to work right now.  thanks